# How to index complex logical expressions?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, lucene

I'm working on a project where a user should be able to define a logical expression in a document. To search the docs, they should provide a set of properties used in the expressions and receive the matching docs where the logical expression is evaluated to `true`.

So, we need to index expressions that look like `[var][operator][value]` where the `[var]` and `[value]` can also be composed as `[var][operator][value]`.

Let's consider an example.
A user specifies the following logical expression:

```
(color=read AND size=small) OR (color=blue AND (size=medium OR size=large)
```

We need to put it in a search engine to be queryable. Then in the query, if pass params `color = red` and `size = small` a user should get the indexed document since the expression is evaluated to `true`. However, if pass `color = blue` and `size = small` then nothing should be returned.

Currently, we can handle them in memory by generating a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) to simplify evaluation. However, it's very slow with a big number of documents that we need to process in every request (fetch all docs, parse expressions to build trees, evaluate expressions).

So we would like to delegate this work to a search engine, if possible.

Is there a way to index such expressions in the form of binary trees (or other forms such as [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)) in a search engine?

And how to build a query so that the expression evaluation would happen in a search engine?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "_the best way to index such logical expressions_". You don't index expressions - you index documents. Your indexes need to define the fields you will be referring to in your expressions: `color`, and `size` in your example. If I have misunderstood the question, can you clarify?

Comment: I know how usually it is, that's why I'm asking here :). 

I need to do it vice versa - index logical expressions and pass attributes in a query.
In our platform customers should be able to define and store complex logical expressions in documents and later query them by providing a set of attributes to be used to evaluate expressions. 
We can have hundreds and thousands of such documents so now without ES we need to load them in memory, evaluate assigned logical expressions, and filter out ineligible docs.

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification. Sounds like you have "[variable] [operator] [value]" clauses (in the simplest case) - so you would need at least those fields. Is that more along the lines you are asking about?

Comment: Each condition in an expression consists of "[variable] [operator] [value]". However, [variable] and [value] also can be represented as "[variable] [operator] [value]" (ie. `(color=read AND size=small) OR (color=blue AND (size=medium OR size=large))`)

Comment: Understood - hence "in the simplest case". As soon as you want to handle logical operators and parentheses, I think you are in the realm of full parsing. Sounds like that is where you are - so, for example, it sounds like you need `size = 'medium' and color = 'red'` to be equivalent to `color= 'red' and size = 'medium'` (and also for much more complex statements). In other words you need your indexed search expressions _and_ your user-provided searches to be in some kind of standardized canonical representation of the logical expression.

Comment: It's possible that you may get better answers if you frame the question in that way, to a specialist audience, rather than as a Lucene/Elasticsearch question. I think that sounds like the underlying problem. Find an approach for that, and  "how to index?" will be answered. Again, apologies if I am still misunderstanding... I certainly do not have an answer, myself.

Comment: Thanks, @andrewjames! I have updated my questions with more details. Hope the problem statement is more clear now.